For a combination painted/bare metal, can I just use a rust inhibiting spray primer or must I use both primer and paint for the small bare metal part?
I bought a window air conditioner that came with a specific bracket designed for that model. I inadvertently scratched some of the paint off of the bracket and I'm now worried about that small exposed area rusting.
I've looked online for canned spray paint, but the questions and answers for the product's page seem to indicate that I should use a primer before applying any spray paint. But, then when I search for primer, the product shown states that it itself prevents rust.
I don't care about how the bracket looks when painted, just so long as it is white and it's only going to be on about a 1-inch square part of the bracket. It would be even less but the spray would inevitably cover more than I need it for.
I'm wondering if I could just use the primer alone to inhibit rust.
Any help would be appreciated.

Primers are not meant as a final coat.
Even if the primer states that it prevents rust, you still need to apply at least 1 more coat of paint over the primer to seal it properly.
Because not all chemical compositions are compatible, use the same brand of paint and primer. Read the cans and use compatible products.
